# Which webpack loader does this require?

Tags: javascript, webpack

This is the error

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| const addProjects = document.querySelector("#add-projects");
| const browseAll = document.querySelector("#browse-all");
> browseProjects?.addEventListener("click", () => {
|     window.location.href = "./dashboard.html";
| });
```

Which loader is required here? I have tried using html-loader but it's not working.

Comment: You need to add babel-loader to support it and configure babel itself